# Storing state in a Grunt task

Tags: gruntjs

I'm facing the following interesting problem:

- I would like to create a Grunt task that is executed at various parts of the build/release process.
- It's possible that one invocation makes some changes to files based on a pattern, e.g. replacing a version number or Git tag like `#develop` in some files.
- A later invocation in the same build needs to "revert" the above changes back to their original values.

Based on the above I would need to find a way to track the changed files from the first invocation, so I can revert the changes in the second step. I can't use a pattern for the second step to avoid false positives.

Example:

1. Start a release - many steps as part of this, compile, uglify/minify, bump version number, create a git release branch.
2. Replace the version numbers of some dependencies, e.g. in `bower.json` - change them from `#develop` to `#1.2.3`
3. Some more steps, including Git commits
4. Replace the version numbers changed above from `#1.2.3` back to `#develop`
5. Additional steps to clean up the release

The last step is difficult since I don't want to change any occurrences of `#1.2.3` that I did not update in the previous step. For this I would need to store the list of changed files somewhere, either in memory, or in a temporary file in the project root, e.g. something like `.grunt-replace`. After reading the file in the last step, it could be deleted by the plugin.

Is anybody using a Grunt plugin like this? How would you solve this? Does Grunt have functionality that would support something like the above, or should I just use the Node.js file API?

Are there other patterns I should consider for keeping some kind of state between Grunt invocations?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a file watcher to keep the grunt process alive and then keep track of state using events.

For instance:

```
var files = [];


module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    watch: {
      files: ['orig.js'],
      tasks: ['my-task']
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');


  grunt.registerTask('my-task', function(){
    // Execute some task
  });

  grunt.event.on('watch', function(action, filepath, project) {
    //add file
    files.push(filepath);

  });

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);

};
```

You can then keep track of which files have been changed and act accordingly.

I have to add though, that this is a bit of a hack. Your build flow shouldn't be stateful, you need to be able to build from scratch.